# Qual a diferença real e quando usar chunk() e chunkById() do laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Não ficou muito claro pra mim o funcionamento na documentação e não achei nenhum conteúdo de explicasse de forma completa como utilizar o chunkById() e a diferença pratica para o chunk();

Como retorno o resultado do chunkById() para a view? como faço a paginação desses registros na view? Da forma abaixo não funciona...

```
DB::table('fornecedores')->orderBy('razao')->chunkById(100, function($fornecedores){
            foreach ($fornecedores as $fornecedor) {
                DB::table('fornecedores')
                    ->where('id', $fornecedor->id);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A diferença entre as duas é como o SQL puro é montado, o `chunkById` usa o `id` e `limit` na hora de montar a sql, enquanto o `chunk` usa `limit` e `offset` por exemplo:

Usando chunkById

```sql
select * from `fornecedores` where `id` > ? order by `razao` asc limit 10
```

Usando chunk

```sql
select * from `fornecedores` order by `razao` asc limit 10 offset 0
```

Chunk não é pra fazer paginação, ele é pra você processar blocos de dados que normalmente seria muito pesado em cpu ou memória pra ser feito tudo junto.

Pra paginar uma query existe o `paginate`

```
public function index()
{
    $fornecedores = DB::table('fornecedores')->orderBy('razao')->paginate(10);

    return view('fornecedores.index', ['fornecedores' => $fornecedores]);
}
```

Depois pra exibir os dados na view fica assim:

```php
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($fornecedores as $fornecedore)
        {{ $fornecedore->id }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

```
{{ $fornecedores->links() }}
```

Recomendo ler a documentação [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination).

Comment: Conheço o paginate, mas por exemplo, tenho 100 mil fornecedores no meu banco, quero limitar para melhorar desempenho. Se eu limitar a 1000 usando o chunk, eu não posso paginar esses 1000? ou o chunk não serve para retornar dados para listagem em view?

Comment: @user143874 depende, você quer paginar somente os 1000 registro ou os 100 mil?

Comment: @user143874 Teria com tu usar simplePaginate pra ser mais eficiente, mas ae teria somente o botão de next e previous, outra coisa que pode ser feito pra melhorar bastante a performace é botar na query as colunas que você precisa, por exemplo se a table fornecedores tiver 50 columns e tu usa só o id e nome na listagem, a query que tu utilizou vai retornar as 50 e não somente as 2 columns utilizadas na view.